# IllegalStateException when MediaCodec.configure Android

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

I try create encoder for "audio/3gpp" and my app crash...

I use this code

```
String mMime = "audio/3gpp";
MediaCodec mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mMime);
MediaFormat mMediaFormat = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat(mMime, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, 1);
mMediaCodec.configure(mMediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mMediaCodec.start();
```

> Exception
>   
> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>   
> android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
>   
> at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:256)
>   
> at com.agent.mobile.TestAppActivity.initMediaCodec(TestAppActivity.java:234)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some mandatory values that must be set in the format.  If you look at the [docs for MediaFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html), it says "all keys not marked optional are mandatory".  If you fail to set a mandatory key, `MediaCodec` throws an error because it has been left in an illegal state.

Add:

```
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, <bit rate>);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE, <sample rate>);
mMediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT, 1);
```

`KEY_MIME` should have been set for you by `createEncoderByType()`.