# Illegal Exception on MediaCodec.configure

Tags: android, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I am trying to learn to encode a mp4 or any sort of video file using the Camera's onPreviewFrame call back.

Currently, I am trying the example codes from this post

[Encoding H.264 from camera with Android MediaCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec)

Unfortunately, I am keep getting an IllegalException on the

mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

From another post
[IllegalStateException when MediaCodec.configure Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233835/illegalstateexception-when-mediacodec-configure-android),
I notice that are some mandatory values I have to set for the MediaCodec.

I tried all the mandatory mediacodec's mandatory values but still no luck of getting past

the IllegalException.

Now I am kinda of running out of ideas to try. Any suggestions, opinions or hints would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

```
11-04 12:27:14.785      175-894/? E/mm-libcamera2﹕ PROFILE HAL: stopPreview(): E: 1383596834.803557773
11-04 12:27:14.795      175-175/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
11-04 12:27:14.795     208-5797/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_shutdown_pp Camera not in streaming mode. Returning.
11-04 12:27:14.795     208-5797/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_ops_deinit: E
11-04 12:27:14.825     175-5814/? E/OMX-VENC-720p﹕ ioctl VEN_IOCTL_CMD_READ_NEXT_MSG failed
11-04 12:27:14.825      175-175/? E/OMX-VENC-720p﹕ Destroy C2D instance
11-04 12:27:14.835      527-539/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
11-04 12:28:17.642    6241-6247/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-04 12:28:17.912      527-539/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
11-04 12:28:17.922     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ sensor_load_chromatix: libchromatix_imx111_preview.so: 30
11-04 12:28:18.032     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_ops_init: E
11-04 12:28:18.042     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
11-04 12:28:18.052     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_legacy_stats_buffer_init: AEC_STATS_BUFNUM
11-04 12:28:18.052     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ mctl_init_stats_proc_info: snap_max_line_cnt =30096
11-04 12:28:18.213    6241-6241/? E/CamcorderProfile﹕ width: 720
11-04 12:28:18.213    6241-6241/? E/CamcorderProfile﹕ height: 480
11-04 12:28:18.213    6241-6241/? E/CamcorderProfile﹕ audioSampleRate: 48000
11-04 12:28:18.213    6241-6241/? E/CamcorderProfile﹕ videoBitRate: 5000000
11-04 12:28:18.213    6241-6241/? E/CamcorderProfile﹕ videoFrameRate: 30
11-04 12:28:18.233      175-617/? E/OMX-VENC-720p﹕ Is component secure 0
11-04 12:28:18.263    6241-6280/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] does not support color format 19
11-04 12:28:18.263    6241-6280/? E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -2147483648
11-04 12:28:18.263    6241-6279/? E/MediaCodec﹕ Codec reported an error. (omx error 0x80001001, internalError -2147483648)
11-04 12:28:18.263    6241-6241/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:259)
            at com.example.mediacodec.AvcEncoder.<init>(AvcEncoder.java:40)
            at com.example.mediacodec.Preview.surfaceCreated(MediaCodecActivity.java:304)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:571)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:833)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1860)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 12:28:20.135      175-617/? E/mm-libcamera2﹕ PROFILE HAL: stopPreview(): E: 1383596900.149872429
11-04 12:28:20.135      175-575/? E/OMXNodeInstance﹕ !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
11-04 12:28:20.135     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ config_shutdown_pp Camera not in streaming mode. Returning.
11-04 12:28:20.145     208-6264/? E/mm-camera﹕ vfe_ops_deinit: E
11-04 12:28:20.165     175-6283/? E/OMX-VENC-720p﹕ ioctl VEN_IOCTL_CMD_READ_NEXT_MSG failed
11-04 12:28:20.165      175-575/? E/OMX-VENC-720p﹕ Destroy C2D instance
11-04 12:28:20.195      527-539/? E/qcom_sensors_hal﹕ hal_process_report_ind: Bad item quality: 11
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
E/ACodec﹕ [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] does not support color format 19
```

Looks like you're trying to use color format 19 (COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar, a/k/a I420) on a Qualcomm device.  A quick test on one of my devices indicates their codecs want color format 21 (COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar, a/k/a NV12).

The buffer-to-buffer tests in the [EncodeDecodeTest sources](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest) show how to query the `MediaCodecInfo` for an appropriate color format.  Since you are receiving input from the Camera, you will want to set the preview format to a semi-planar layout (NV21), and then do the [U/V swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match) before handing it to the MediaCodec.

If you have Android 4.3 or later, you can skip all of the format gymnastics and use the `Surface` preview output.  See the [CameraToMpegTest sources](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest) for an example.