# OMXCodec die when start decoding

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I'd like to retrieve frames from video file.

My code followed the article [Use Android Hardware Decoder with OMXCodec in NDK](https://vec.io/posts/use-android-hardware-decoder-with-omxcodec-in-ndk), and also referred the code of AwesomePlayer.cpp(AOSP) and libstagefright.cpp(ffmpeg). But it still hangs whenever OMXCodec start decoding. I have no idea what the problem is.

I'd grateful for any help.

the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    OMXClient mClient;
    status_t ret = mClient.connect();
    LOGD("connect status is %d\n", ret);

    sp<DataSource> mDs = DataSource::CreateFromURI("file:///sdcard/display/lwtwjod.mp4");
    off64_t size = 0;
    ret = mDs->getSize(&size);
    LOGD("getSize[ret=%d]: %lld\n", ret, size);

    sp<MediaExtractor> mMe = MediaExtractor::Create(mDs);
    size_t tracksNum = mMe->countTracks();
    LOGD("%u tracks\n", tracksNum);

    sp<MediaSource> mMs;

    bool hasVideo = false;
    for(size_t i = 0; i != mMe->countTracks(); i++){
    sp<MetaData> mMd_track = mMe->getTrackMetaData(i);
        const char *_mime;
    mMd_track->findCString(kKeyMIMEType, &_mime);
        LOGD("the mime is %s\n", _mime);
        String8 mime = String8(_mime);

        if (!strncasecmp(mime.string(), "video/", 6)) {
        LOGD("find video track!\n");
        hasVideo = true;
        mMs = mMe->getTrack(i);
        int wid, hei;
        mMd_track->findInt32(kKeyWidth, &wid);
        mMd_track->findInt32(kKeyHeight, &hei);
        LOGD("width: %d, height: %d\n", wid, hei);
        break;
    }
    }

    if(hasVideo){
    sp<MediaSource> decoder = 
        OMXCodec::Create(mClient.interface(), mMs->getFormat(),
                 false, mMs, 
                 NULL, OMXCodec::kClientNeedsFramebuffer);
    LOGD("start decoding..\n");
    ret = decoder->start(); // hangs here
    LOGD("decoding return: %d\n", ret);

    for(;;){
        MediaBuffer *buffer;
        buffer = NULL;
        ret = decoder->read(&buffer);
        LOGD("read decoded buffer result: %d\n", ret);
        break;
    }
    }    
}
```

The logcat output:

```
I/OMXClient( 5470): Using client-side OMX mux.
D/NativeCodec( 5470): connect status is 0
D/NativeCodec( 5470): getSize[ret=0]: 165748860
D/NativeCodec( 5470): 2 tracks
D/NativeCodec( 5470): the mime is video/avc
D/NativeCodec( 5470): find video track!
D/OMXCodec( 5470): Successfully allocated OMX node 'OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc'
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] AVC profile = 100 (High), level = 31
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] video dimensions are 1280 x 720
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] Crop rect is 1280 x 720 @ (0, 0)
D/NativeCodec( 5470): start decoding..
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocating 2 buffers of size 2097152 on input port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8e39390 on input port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8e393e0 on input port
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  No color conversion required
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocating 15 buffers of size 1433600 on output port
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): GET_MV_BUFFER_SIZE returned: Size: 245760 and alignment: 8192
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9b08 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9b58 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9ba8 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9bf8 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9c48 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9c98 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9ce8 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9d38 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9d88 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9dd8 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9e28 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9e78 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9ec8 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9f18 on output port
I/OMXCodec( 5470): [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] allocated buffer 0xb8eb9f68 on output port
E/OMXNodeInstance(  197): !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9f68 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9f18 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9ec8 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9e78 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9e28 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9dd8 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9d88 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9d38 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9ce8 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9c98 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9c48 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9bf8 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9ba8 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9b58 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8eb9b08 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8e393e0 successful
I/OMXNodeInstance(  197): OMX_FreeBuffer for buffer header 0xb8e39390 successful
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197): 
E/OMX-VDEC-1080P(  197):  Error in ioctl read next msg
E/        (  197): 
E/        (  197):  Destroy C2D instance
E/        (  197): 
E/        (  197):  Destroy C2D instance
```

Comment: This: `E/OMXNodeInstance(  197): !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...` suggests your program is crashing.  Do you see any additional logs from pid 5470 after that point?  FWIW, you don't need to use non-public APIs on API 16+; see e.g. http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#ExtractMpegFramesTest

Comment: This log entry comes out only because I pressed CTRL-C to interrupt the running program. I invoke my c++ program via JNI instead of an individual executable binary, and it works now! Though I have no idea what's the reason...

Comment: the following SO thread may help; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776680/illegal-exception-on-mediacodec-configure